A difficult integral inequality
Let  $ f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $  be a differentiable function with continuous derivative such that  $ f(1) = 0 $ , show that:
$$ 4 \int_0^1 x^2 |f'(x)|^2 \, dx \geq \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 \, dx + \left( \int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx \right)^2 $$
This is a problem that requires a certain level of skill. Assuming  $ f(0) = 1 $ , this problem can be approached by multiplying both sides by the integral of  $ (1 - f(x))^2 $  and then applying Hölder's inequality. I am curious if there is a more general form of this inequality or if it can be generalized.
The general form of Hölder's inequality is given by:
$$
\left( \int |a(x) b(x)| \, dx \right) \leq \left( \int |a(x)|^p \, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \left( \int |b(x)|^q \, dx \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
$$
where  $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $  and  $ p, q > 1 $ .

Take $f$ to be constant, say 1.

@Nandor. A constant $\neq 0$ does not work as counterexample as $f(1)$ should be $0$.

While I agree that the question is formulated not in the best way ("Show that XXX" without any motivation), it is in fact a strengthening of the very classical and important Hardy's inequality, and seems to be quite non-trivial (full disclosure: I just solved it and greatly enjoyed doing so, and was in the middle of writing an answer when the question was closed). Voting for reopen.

@AlekseiKulikov: I would surely vote to reopen if the question were reformulated, say, on Riemannian manifolds. Or at least on open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

@AlexM. claimed inequality is quite delicate and dependent on the interval, in particular none of the constants can be improved. If you didn't care for the constants surely there are generalizations to nice manifolds (with boundary if needed be), but if you do care I don't see how to get very far from the interval (maybe you can go to the ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, if even).

Given that the question is expressed as "Show such-and such", it is not really a question, it's a command. The phrasing indicates that the poster knows the statement to be true, and is issuing a challenge. So is it really a question, asking for help from research colleagues? Challenges are all very well, and can be nice and entertaining, but they just seem wrong for this forum. Unless this is a misinterpretation of what's going on here, I don't vote to reopen.

The desired inequality holds, and it was somewhat less trivial than I expected. As a first step, we will eliminate all the derivatives. We will denote $g(t) = |f'(t)|$ and on the right-hand side estimate $|f(x)| \le \int_x^1g(t)dt$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Rewriting everything in terms of $g$ we get
$$ 4\int_0^1 x^2g(x)^2dx\ge\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1g(t)dt\right)^2dx + \left(\int_0^1\int_x^1g(t)dt\right)^2.$$
In the right-hand side we will rewrite it as a double integral over $[0, 1]^2$ (for the second term we also first have to switch integrals). We get
$$4\int_0^1x^2g(x)^2dx \ge\int_0^1\int_0^1g(s)g(t)(\min(s, t)+st)dsdt.$$
For simplicity, denote $h(t) = tg(t)$. Then on the left-hand side we have $4\int_0^1 h(x)^2dx$, while on the right-hand side the factor will turn to $\frac{\min(s, t)}{st} + 1 = \frac{1}{\max(s, t)}+1$. This reminded me of the Hardy's inequality, and more precisely of the proof I read here Identities and inequalities in analysis and probability. In fact, if we didn't have $+1$ then this would be the end of the story. On the other hand, in the Hardy's inequality we have integral over the whole real line so we might want to try to exploit the fact that we have extra $[1, +\infty)$ to work with. Repeating the proof from that link we will get that $\int_0^1 h(x)^2(4-2\sqrt{x})dx$ is at least $\int_0^1\int_0^1 h(s)h(t) \frac{1}{\max(s, t)}dsdt$ (the value $4-2\sqrt{x}$ is the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}\max(x, y)}dy$). So, it remains to show that
$$\int_0^1 2\sqrt{x}h^2(x)dx \ge \int_0^1\int_0^1 h(s)h(t)dsdt.$$
Surprisingly, it can be proven by the same integral of a square trick. We have
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (\sqrt{x}h(x) - \sqrt{y}h(y))^2 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{xy}}dxdy \ge 0.$$
If we expand this we will get
$$2\int_0^1\int_0^1h(y)^2\frac{x}{2\sqrt{xy}}dxdy \ge\int_0^1\int_0^1 h(x)h(y)dxdy,$$
where the first $2$ is by symmetry (terms with $h(x)^2$ and $h(y)^2$ give the same value). Taking the $dx$ integral the left-hand side becomes $\int_0^1 2\sqrt{y}h(y)^2dy$, which is exactly what we wanted.
Now, if I was a cosmic entity beyond human comprehension then after the first step I could've just said "Consider the inequality
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^{3/2}g(x)-y^{3/2}g(y))^2\frac{1}{2\sqrt{xy}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\max(x, y)}\right)dxdy\ge 0,$$
which after expanding the square and integrating becomes exactly what we need.", but then I think everyone (including myself) would have rightfully questioned my humanity.

This is really a nice inequality with a nice proof! I tried to use Schur test with the kernel $1+\frac{1}{\max{t,s}}$ but I get 16 instead of 4, which is horrible. But the same happens forgetting the 1, that is for the pure Hardy. Nevertheless Schur works for Hardy without reducing it to a double integral...I am puzzled why this happens.

I thought again at this inequality but finally, M. Sobajima explained to me what I once already knew and forgot in the meantime. Maybe it is useful for somebody else, even though the previous answer is certainly correct.
In all Hardy-type inequalities, with or without remainder, the Euler differential operator $xD$ appears and it is therefore natural to make an exponential change of variable, namely $x=e^{-s}$.
Then (we may assume that $f \geq 0$, otherwise we take $\tilde f(x)=\int_x^1 |f'(t)|dt$)
$$\int_0^1 x^2f'^2dx=\int_0^\infty |f'(e^{-s})|^2 e^{-3s} ds=\int_0^\infty g'(s)^2 e^{-s} ds
$$
with $g(s)=f(e^{-s})$. Set now $v(s)=g(s)e^{-\frac s2}$.
Then $g'(s)e^{-\frac s2}=v'+\frac 12 v$ and
$$\int_0^\infty g'(s)^2 e^{-s} ds=\int_0^\infty \left( v'(s)+\frac 12 v(s)\right )^2ds=\\\int_0^\infty v'(s)^2 ds+\frac 14 \int_0^\infty   v^2(s)= \int_0^\infty v'(s)^2 ds+\frac 14 \int_0^1   f^2(x)
dx$$
since the integral of cross product vanishes by the boundary conditions. Note that this is already Hardy's inequality, simply forgetting the first term in the last sum, and this is probably the easiest. proof To get the remainder it suffices to bound the square of the integral of $f$ with $4$ of the first term. Integrating by parts, the boundary terms vanish and by Cauchy Schwartz
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty v(s) e^{-\frac s2}ds=2\int_0^\infty v'(s) e^{-\frac s2} ds \leq 2\left (\int_0^\infty v'(s)^2 \right )^{\frac 12} \left (\int_0^\infty e^{-s}ds \right )^{\frac 12} = 2\left (\int_0^\infty v'(s)^2\right)^{\frac 12}
$$
